# why creating a style object to give style to the component show me random error in reacjs?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, oop, styling

I want to add style to the container class but myStyle is showing errors? what is the problem please help!

```
import React from 'react'
```

export default function About() {
let myStyle{
color:'white',
backgroundColor:'balck'
}
return (
<>

```
    <h1 className='my-3'>about me</h1>
            <div className="accordion accordion-flush" id="accordionFlushExample">
        <div className="accordion-item">
        <h2 className="accordion-header" id="flush-headingOne">
            <button style={myStyle} className="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#flush-collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseOne">
            Accordion Item #1
            </button>
        </h2>
        <div stle={myStyle} id="flush-collapseOne" className="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="flush-headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample">
            <div className="accordion-body">Placeholder content for this accordion, which is intended to demonstrate the <code>.accordion-flush</code> className. This is the first item's accordion body.</div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div className="accordion-item">
        <h2 className="accordion-header" id="flush-headingTwo">
            <button style={myStyle} className="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#flush-collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseTwo">
            Accordion Item #2
            </button>
        </h2>
        <div stle={myStyle} id="flush-collapseTwo" className="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="flush-headingTwo" data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample">
            <div className="accordion-body">Placeholder content for this accordion, which is intended to demonstrate the <code>.accordion-flush</code> className. This is the second item's accordion body. Let's imagine this being filled with some actual content.</div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div className="accordion-item">
        <h2 className="accordion-header" id="flush-headingThree">
            <button stle={myStyle} className="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#flush-collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseThree">
            Accordion Item #3
            </button>
        </h2>
        <div stle={myStyle} id="flush-collapseThree" className="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="flush-headingThree" data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample">
            <div className="accordion-body">Placeholder content for this accordion, which is intended to demonstrate the <code>.accordion-flush</code> className. This is the third item's accordion body. Nothing more exciting happening here in terms of content, but just filling up the space to make it look, at least at first glance, a bit more representative of how this would look in a real-world application.</div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div className='container'> 
<button type="button" className="btn btn-primary my-3" >Primary</button>
</div>
</>
```

)
}

Comment: It's syntax error. It should be `let myStyle = { color:'white', backgroundColor:'balck' }`

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: @IamL check it here

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
import React from "react";

export default function About() { let myStyle = { color:'white', backgroundColor:'black' } 
return ( <> <div>
<h1 className='my-3'>about me</h1>
<div className="accordion accordion-flush" id="accordionFlushExample">
<div className="accordion-item">
<h2 className="accordion-header" id="flush-headingOne">
<button style={myStyle} className="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#flush-collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseOne">
Accordion Item #1
</button>
</h2>
<div stle={myStyle} id="flush-collapseOne" className="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="flush-headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample">
<div className="accordion-body">Placeholder content for this accordion, which is intended to demonstrate the <code>.accordion-flush</code> className. This is the first item's accordion body.</div>
</div>
</div>
<div className="accordion-item">
<h2 className="accordion-header" id="flush-headingTwo">
<button style={myStyle} className="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#flush-collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseTwo">
Accordion Item #2
</button>
</h2>
<div style={myStyle} id="flush-collapseTwo" className="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="flush-headingTwo" data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample">
<div className="accordion-body">Placeholder content for this accordion, which is intended to demonstrate the <code>.accordion-flush</code> className. This is the second item's accordion body. Let's imagine this being filled with some actual content.</div>
</div>
</div>
<div className="accordion-item">
<h2 className="accordion-header" id="flush-headingThree">
<button style={myStyle} className="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#flush-collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseThree">
Accordion Item #3
</button>
</h2>
<div style={myStyle} id="flush-collapseThree" className="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="flush-headingThree" data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample">
<div className="accordion-body">Placeholder content for this accordion, which is intended to demonstrate the <code>.accordion-flush</code> className. This is the third item's accordion body. Nothing more exciting happening here in terms of content, but just filling up the space to make it look, at least at first glance, a bit more representative of how this would look in a real-world application.</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div className='container'> 
<button type="button" className="btn btn-primary my-3" >Primary</button>
</div>
</>
)}
```

You've initialised myStyle in a wrong manner it is

```
let myStyle = { color:'white', backgroundColor:'black' }
```

while it was

```
let myStyle { color:'white', backgroundColor:'balck' }
```

Style reference inside div was also wrong for several divs where it is stle but it should be Style

There is also a div missing but it might be due to copy pasting error

READ & WRITE PROGRAMS WITH INITIALISED VARS IN MIND :)